# Supermicro X9SPV, no video

Tags: supermicro

I just got my dearly awaited [X9SPV-LN4F-3QE](http://www.supermicro.com/products/motherboard/xeon/qm77/x9spv-ln4f-3qe.cfm) motherboard. My joy is somewhat muddled by not being able to get any video out from the on board graphics however.

I have removed hard drives, tested removing and one by one replacing the memory modules (what I had lying about at home, Kingston MB1066K2, 2*4GB). No result. Interesting enough, I **can** access the IPMI interface. However, accessing the KVM interface it says "No video".

Any ideas?

Comment: BIOS option to control which video is used?

Comment: @BradPatton: I can't access the BIOS, as far as I can tell (somewhat of an IPMI noob, however, might be missing something). There is a jumper which is not documented in the manual, JP1, which the onboard printing identifies as "VGA SEL", with options "From BMC" or "From CPU". It came installed as "From BMC", but changing it to "From CPU" did not make any difference.

Comment: From the IPMI interface, I can find that the POST sequence stops at code 55. These codes don't seems to be documented, though...